# Return different UITableViewCell types in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` loading it from a xib file following the helpful guidance of; [How do you load custom UITableViewCells from xib files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files).

I only want this custom cell for the first row in my `UITableView`, the others are simple labels and the standard `UITableViewCell` is fine.

The problem is when I include the custom cell the whole `UITableView` isn't shown and the screen is blank except for the navigation elements. Using just the standard cells the table appears fine so it is something to do with the custom cell.

Here is the code I have to return the cells;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row == 0)  {
        ArticleDetailCell *cell = (ArticleDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Detail", reuseIdentifier]];

        if(!cell) {
            // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ArticleDetailCell" owner:self options:nil];
            // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
            cell = (ArticleDetailCell *)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        [[(ArticleDetailCell *)cell judges] setText:[[self caseBaseArticle] judges]];
        [[(ArticleDetailCell *)cell judgementDate] setText:[[self caseBaseArticle] judgmentDate]];
        [[(ArticleDetailCell *)cell court] setText:[[self caseBaseArticle] court]];

        return cell;

    } else {    
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

        if(!cell) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier] autorelease];
            [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:1];
            [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            [[cell textLabel] setText:articleRowTitles[indexPath.row-1]];
        }

        if ([self tableRowHasContentDetail:indexPath]) {
            [self enableTableCell:&cell];
        }else {
            [self disableTableCell:&cell];
        }       

        return cell;
    }
}
```

The ArticleDetailCell is loaded from the xib file ok and the properties get set correctly as I can see this in the debugger. Stopping at `return cell` when I print the custom cell object from `(gdb)` I get;

```
<ArticleDetailCell: 0x4bc22b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 367); autoresize = W+TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x4bc23c0>>
```

Is there some problem with the cell dereferencing? I'll still getting my head around retain counts and when they do and don't increment.

Why does the whole UITableView disappear because of a problem with a single cell?

**EDIT:** FYI @BoltClock

```
- (void)disableTableCell:(UITableViewCell **)cell {
    [*cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    [*cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [[*cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
}
```

Comment: Just a quickie: in your if statement when you customize your labels, you don't have to cast `cell` to `ArticleDetailCell` each time because you already declare and initialize it as an `ArticleDetailCell`. What do your `enableTableCell:` and `disableTableCell:` methods look like?

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for the refactoring hint, must have left that in from before I fixed the problem creating the custom cell as only a UITableViewCell

Comment: @BoltClock added the disableTableCell method to question (enable is almost the same but uses different values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was mostly with the xib file for the custom cell. Strict following of [Loading Custom Cells from NIB Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) from the Apple Developer Center did the trick.

The key thing was to set the `File's Owner` in the custom cell to be the type of `UITableViewController` where I'd use the cell. The `UITableViewController` also had an `IBOutlet` property for the custom `UITableViewCell` which was used to connect the `File's Owner` to the custom cell in the xib file.

Importantly the Identifer was set in the xib file for the Table View Cell so that it matches the value used in the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method.

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ended up like this where `articleDetail` is the `IBOutlet` property;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row == 0)  {
        ArticleDetailCell  *cell = (ArticleDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Detail",reuseIdentifier]];

        if(!cell) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ArticleDetailCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = articleDetail;
            [self setArticleDetail:nil];
        }

        [[cell judges] setText:[[self caseBaseArticle] judges]];
        [[cell judgementDate] setText:[[self caseBaseArticle] judgmentDate]];
        [[cell court] setText:[[self caseBaseArticle] court]];

        return cell;

    } else {    
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

        if(!cell) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier] autorelease];
            [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:1];
            [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            [[cell textLabel] setText:articleRowTitles[indexPath.row-1]];
        }

        if ([self tableRowHasContentDetail:indexPath]) {
            [self enableTableCell:&cell];
        }else {
            [self disableTableCell:&cell];
        }       

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is **reuseIdentifier** defined? Is it always available to this method?

Comment: yes it's just a static NSString within the UIViewController implementation.