# 3 different UITableViewCell in one cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I add 3 different `UITableViewCell` in one method:

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I appreciated if you can help me for this implementation with sample code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return different UITableViewCell types in cellForRowAtIndexPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393745/return-different-uitableviewcell-types-in-cellforrowatindexpath)

Comment: Add two, then one more?  (I don't get your question.  You can have an unlimited number of different cell formats, just give them different reuse identifiers.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to design each one on your view controller and give each a different cell identifier. In your cellForRowAtIndex deque the cell matching the specific identifier.

Comment: thanks for your reply would you please give me a sample code?