# Nib from different class

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, class, nib

I have tried several other examples, on this site and others, but for the life of me I cannot get this to work.

I have a NIB file which is a part of the class "ViewController2". I need to use a few of the views in this NIB file in my "ViewController1" class.

Each time I call

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ViewController2" owner:self options:nil];
```

it causes a crash, saying that one of my `UIButton`s is not `KVC` compliant, but I have properly linked all the buttons and outlets, to no avail.

Any help would be extremely appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Will the suggestion on the accepted answer of this question work for you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849330/one-xib-file-with-multiple-files-owners

Comment: I tried that trojanfoe, but after entering the following code:

VC2 *VC2 = [[VC2 alloc]init];    

[self addChildViewController:VC2];
    
[_containerView addSubview:advancedMenu.stopwatchView];

I get the following error:

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<mainMenuViewController 0x10364130> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key customAboutBtn.'

Comment: the `owner` should be `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is faster at least 3 times than `NSBundle`:

```
ViewController2 *_viewController2 = [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

it will load the `nib` file and it will create a new instance of the `ViewController2` class.

---

**NB**: if you'd like to use an already existing instance of the `ViewController2` class for the `nib`, you will need to set that instance as `owner`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you load a nib and set the `owner:` property to `self`, iOS tries to wire up the outlets with KVC. If you don't have a UIButton with a keyPath that matches the one in the xib file inside of the class you're currently in, you'll get the crash. You need to set `owner:` to `nil`.