# custom uitableViewCell in controller which inherit from UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to create custom UiTableViewCell, and it works, when I create TableView, like in this [example](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/), by inherit from UIViewController. But when I create controller which inherit from UITableViewController (not UIViewController), and in xib create UITableViewCell, and of course hook up IBOutlet, i get this error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:5678
```

2011-05-06 07:21:34.107 tabela[11424:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { return cellOne; }
```

Comment: This was asked literally an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906592/initialize-custom-uitableviewcell/5906614#5906614 . Short story is, make your custom UITableViewCell programmatically (rather than in IB).

Comment: show your code for cellForRow

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample reference

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// In your case it has to be the custom cell object here.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AnIdentifierString"];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"AnIdentifierString"] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"This text will appear in the cell";


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: yeah I know, but I only want to check if this is working so I wrote: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return cellOne;
    
} cellOne is of course hooked up

Comment: pls see if this helps http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/

Comment: Yes, I know that this is working, there is hundreds ways to create custom uitableviewCell, but I want to know WHY MY implementation doesn't work.