# iphone+same xib for different class

Tags: iphone, xib

I have two class and in both class tableview uses custom nib file(for table cell)as well as i make IBOutlet instance of myview controller to that custom cell nib file  but i can not use same nib for both class becuase i have give file owner of that xib to the myviewcontroller so when i used that one in another class it give error so any ideas so use the same xib for both the view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse your custom table cell with multiple view controllers, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files/1939305#1939305). The two methods described there let you load your custom table cell from a nib file without having to set the File's Owner to your specific controller.