# Second Cell appearing only after first cell is selected in Tableview ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, selection, cell

When I run my ios app, only the first cell displays in the TableView, then when clicked the second cell displays. I would like them both to display at the same time, but I cannot figure out this behavior.

Here is the code for my view did load

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProductCellId";

    ProductTableCell *cell = 
        (ProductTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.productCell;
    }    

    Product *product = [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell configureForProduct:product];

    return cell;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are loading your cell from Interface builder try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProductTableCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }


Product *product = [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell configureForProduct:product];


    return cell;
}
```

Change this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProductCellId";
```

to:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProductTableCell";
```

You can find additional information for what you are trying to do in this question: [Load cells from XIB files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files)

Comment: Thanks for the response. When my (cell== nil) condition has this  { [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductTableCell" owner:self options:nil];cell = self.productCell; } it does the behavior i described. When I put (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; } the app simply crashes. Any further suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: @Mikez Why does the app crash, what is the error?? I am assuming ProductTableCell is a UITableView sub class so to be more specfic you would have to do [[[ProductTableCell alloc], that is probably why it is crashing, since it would crash with a ClassCastException on the dequeu. Edited my answer with the new code.

Comment: Okay, when i used this line cell = [[[ProductTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; it didn't crash, but the list was completely empty

Comment: @Mikez Well that doesn't have to do with tableviewcell anymore, but with filling the cells correctly. I think you will find this tutorial helpful: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/03/uitableview-drill-down-table-view.html

Comment: Wouldn't the cells be filled correctly if they worked before (all the information was correctly placed on the first cell, and the second when the first was selected)?

Comment: What do you load here exactly :         [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductTableCell" owner:self options:nil]; try leaving that line as well as my code in the cell == nil

Comment: The list is still empty afterwards

Comment: @Mikez see my edited question, that should solve the problem.

Comment: Still have the same problem. I made the ID of the table cell ProductCellId so that was correct initially. Thank you for the link and your help, I will investigate further.