# How to show a .xib file in a TableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a .xib with an image and a label in the potition that i want..
And i want in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function to set image and label.text then to add then view in the cell and show the cell

Comment: The full description about the uitableview is at
http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this:
[How do you load custom UITableViewCells from Xib files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files)

But i do not recommend to load UITableViewCells from xib.

You loose performance on a very critical part.

I recommend to create you UITableViewCell subclasses by code. Because inflating a XIB(XML) during scrolling will create buckings.

If you wan't to have a nice, snappy app, then code instead of XIB (at least the UITableViewCell subclasses).

Comment: true, although the UINib option available in iOS4+ allows the nib file to be cached in memory (not having to read it from disk every time), improving performance. You can get very good, fluid scrolling using this, even with complex cells.