# Custom UITableViewCell button action not calling?

Tags: iphone

I have a custom cell with a button inside. My problem is action method is not calling when click on cell button

Right now I'm doing

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblHomeView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    MyCell * mycell2 = ((MyCell*)cell);
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

        [mycell2.column1 addTarget:self action:@selector(column1Selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [mycell2.column2 addTarget:self action:@selector(column1Selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];        
    }
```

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath method and my method is:

```
- (void) column1Selected: (id) sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[ UIAlertView alloc]                          
                          initWithTitle: @" Alert"                          
                          message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"button %d",((UIButton *) sender).tag]
                          delegate: nil                          
                          cancelButtonTitle: @" OK"                          
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];    
    [alert show] ;
    [alert release];
}
```

Any tips? Thank's

Comment: But you're not adding the target action method to the button, instead you're adding it to the column itself.You say mycell2.column1 addTarget..... which means the method would get called if you touched the column, not the button.

Comment: @interface MyCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIButton * column1;
    UIButton * column2;

Comment: have you created property and synthesis of your buttons ?

Comment: yes, i have created property and synthesis

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you should send message `addTarget:action:forControlEvent:` to instance of UIButton, but you are sending it to something different. Are `column1` and `column2` buttons? If your `MyCell` is loaded from nib file, make sure IBOutlets correctly set up. And make sure that you load xib files correctly! Take a look at [example of loading custom cells from xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files)

Comment: column1 and column2 are buttons

Comment: What about second part of my answer? Are you trying to load buttons xib with your custom table view cell?