# Custom UITableViewCell Not Using .xib (Most Likely Because of Flaw in init Method)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I subclassed the UITableViewCell in order to customize it, but I think I'm missing something because: 1) It's not working and 2) There are a couple of things I'm confused on. Along with customizing the look of the .xib file, I also changed the backgroundView, and that part is working fine. The part that I least understand/am most confused about is the init method, so I posted that here. If it turns out that is correct, please tell me so I can post more code that *may* be the cause.

**This is the init method, which I customized.** I'm sort of confused around the "style" idea and I think I'm just returning a normal UITableViewCell with a different backgroundView. I mean, there's nothing in there that refers to the .xib or does anything but change the .backgroundView from the self:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier wait: (float) wait fadeOut: (float) fadeOut fadeIn: (float) fadeIn playFor: (float) playFor
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        CueLoadingView* lview = [[CueLoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 53)];
        self.backgroundView = lview;

        [self setWait:wait]; // in turn edits the lview through the backgrounView pointer
        [self setFadeOut:fadeOut];
        [self setFadeIn:fadeIn];
        [self setPlayFor:playFor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Other than the .xib and several setters and getters, this is the only real part of my code, that relates to retrieving a cell.

Additional Information:

1) This is my .xib, which is linked to the class.
[image]

2) This is the code that calls/creates the UITableView (the delegate/view controller):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CueTableCell";

    CueTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CueTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier wait:5.0 fadeOut:1.0 fadeIn:1.0 playFor:10.0];
        [cell updateBarAt:15];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way (available since iOS 5.0) to create a custom table view cell in a nib file is to use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` in the table view controller. The big advantage is that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` then automatically instantiates a cell from the nib file if necessary. You don't need the `if (cell == nil) ...` part anymore.

In `viewDidLoad` of the table view controller you add

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CueTableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CueTableCell"];
```

and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you just do

```
CueTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CueTableCell"];
// setup cell
return cell;
```

Cells loaded from a nib file are instantiated using `initWithCoder`, you can override that in your subclass if necessary. For modifications to the UI elements, you should override `awakeFromNib` (don't forget to call "super").

Comment: This is the most elegant solution.

Comment: This looks great, but for some reason the class that is the delegate of the table view controller doesn't have a tableView variable. The function tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: does, but not the viewDidLoad...

Comment: forCellReuseIdentifier is the correct not forCellWithReuseIdentifier and it's not possible to control the FileOwner in the XIB, and when you don't check against 0 you have a chance that it will be 0...anybody even Apple promises anything in a method' description.

Comment: @BootMaker: I have fixed that, thank you! (forCellWithReuseIdentifier is for collection views.) - I do not understand the second part of your comment.

Comment: @Martin In your solution - which is the official one, no doubt - there is no effect of the cell XIB's file owner, so you couldn't use it. This solution will work with TableView Controller but not with added tableView with simple UIViewController, and I spent time debugging this solution several times in special cases, so I don't really use it even with simple tableView Controller. Regarding zero checking it's just nitpicking, I mean if I don't close out something explicitly it could happen...even the Apple docs says...maybe you know this too from your practice.

Comment: question was how to not use .xib :)

Comment: @dollar8: As I understood it, the question was *why* the XIB file is not used. (I sincerely hope that OP would not accept an answer which did not help to solve the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the cell from the .xib instead:

```
if ( cell == nil ) {
    cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellXIBName" owner:nil options:nil][0];
}

// set the cell's properties
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CueTableCell";

    CueTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CueTableCell XibName" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}
```