# Fill a tableview with content of array NOT working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

Basically what i want to do is i want to fill a table view with strings from an array. I've made a second UIviewcontroller and a custom cell with that show an image and two other labels. But when i run the code, there is no error messages but the tableview is blank, almost like its not recognizing the code at all. I have declared a delegate and datasource for it in the .h file.

```
    #import "ViewController4.h"
    #import "Cell.h"
    #import "XMLparse.h"

    @interface ViewController4 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController4

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)objects {
    if (!Datarray) {
        Datarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return Datarray;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Datarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"USD",@"EUR",@"JPY",@"BGN",@"CZK",@"DKK",@"GBP",@"HUF",@"LTL",@"PLN",@"RON",@"SEK",@"CHF",@"NOK",@"HRK",@"RUB",@"TRY",@"AUD",@"BRL",@"CAD",@"CNY",@"HKD",@"IDR",@"ILS",@"INR",@"KRW",@"MXN",@"MYR",@"NZD",@"PHP",@"SGD",@"THB",@"ZAR", nil];
    Tableview.delegate = self;
    XMLparse *datee = [[XMLparse alloc]init];
    [datee loadDataFromXML];
    Date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last updated: %@",[datee tid]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableview:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [Datarray count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    Cell *cell = (Cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

  //  cell.ratename.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 //   cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.currencyname.text = [Datarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}




@end
```

Comment: Did you debug? Are you ever setting the table data source? Are you ever asking the table to reload?

Comment: set datasource and delegates

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `self` to datasource property of UITableView. I suggest you the following code edited.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Datarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"USD",@"EUR",@"JPY",@"BGN",@"CZK",@"DKK",@"GBP",@"HUF",@"LTL",@"PLN",@"RON",@"SEK",@"CHF",@"NOK",@"HRK",@"RUB",@"TRY",@"AUD",@"BRL",@"CAD",@"CNY",@"HKD",@"IDR",@"ILS",@"INR",@"KRW",@"MXN",@"MYR",@"NZD",@"PHP",@"SGD",@"THB",@"ZAR", nil];
    Tableview.delegate = self;
    Tableview.dataSource = self;    // <---- added code for setting datasource.
    XMLparse *datee = [[XMLparse alloc]init];
    [datee loadDataFromXML];
    Date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last updated: %@",[datee tid]];
}
```

Comment: Changing data source to self ended with this error code:2014-02-22 14:15:44.798 Pickerview[15332:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Fredrik/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/188ABEBA-9EFB-4548-84F1-2B0B9A0277CF/Pickerview.app> (loaded)' with name 'Cell''

Comment: @user3338161 Does your project have Cell.xlb?

Comment: Yes, It's named table.xib thought

Comment: @user3338161 try to remove Cell.xib and Cell.h/m from your project then add them to it again.

Comment: @user3338161 If your project is available since iOS 5. I'm sure the link (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15591474/579236) will be helpful for you.

Comment: well, now i get this error message instead:Pickerview[15563:70b] -[UITableViewCell currencyname]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1090297d0
2014-02-22 14:35:19.250 Pickerview[15563:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell currencyname]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1090297d0'

Comment: @user3338161 Does `Cell` class have `currencyname` property in Cell.h as public property? This error message is occurred due to absence of a setter of a property specified.

Comment: This is whats in the Cell.h file:#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

(at)interface Cell : UITableViewCell

(at)property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *currencyname;               (at)end

Comment: @user3338161 check two points. First, select Cell.xib in left tree navigation, then check that 'Custom Class' section in 'Identity inspector' tab in 'Utilities' is set to `Cell`. Second, check whether the IBOutlet is actually connected to a UILabel control on xib or not.  Anyway, I'm sure that you can find a way to solve the problem yourself with my answers.