# UIImageView does not initially display image in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `UITableView` that loads images from a service. It fetches URLs and downloads the images with `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL`:

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, _, error) -> Void in
                            guard
                                let data = data where error == nil,
                                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                                else {
                                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                                    return
                            }
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                [unowned self] in
                                self.pictureView.image = image
                                self.pictureView.layoutIfNeeded()
                            }
                        }).resume()
```

The `UIImageView` is an outlet to a storyboard scene. The `UIImageView` content mode is Aspect Fit.

The `UIImageView` for visible cells initially displays empty (no image) even though I've confirmed an image was set. It isn't until the cell is scrolled off/on screen that the cell will redraw(?) and display the image.

So this seems like some kind of timing issue, but I can't figure it out. I've tried calling all of the following within the `dispatch_async` block after the image is set:

```
self.pictureView.setNeedsDisplay()
self.pictureView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
self.pictureView.setNeedsLayout()
self.pictureView.reloadInputViews()
```

None of these fix the problem. What is causing this image to only display after the cell is scrolled out/into view?

EDIT:
It may be important to note that this is taking place inside a nib and the associated class. The nib is loaded, then I kick off the download. I'm wondering if the nib lays itself out, and by the time my image is downloaded and set on the `UIImageView` the layout pass has completed. Then by moving the cell (containing the nib) off/on screen the cell performs a layout again and everything is displayed properly. Just a guess, and I'm still stuck on this.

EDIT 2:
Further clarification of the process:

1) My `UIViewController` contains a `UITableView`.

2) This `UITableView` loads cells from a custom `UITableViewCell` class called PostCell.

3) The entire contents of PostCell are a single view loaded from a nib called PostView (with a PostView class). That load occurs during `init:style:reuseIdentifier` in PostCell:

```
postView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("PostView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? PostView
```

4) I then set a Post object on `postView`:

```
postView.post = Post
```

Note that this occurs AFTER `awakeFromNib()` is called on PostView.

5) The `post` property on PostView has a `didSet` observer which kicks off the image download based on a URL in the `post` object (code above). The image is downloaded and set on the `UIImageView` named `pictureView`.

Edit 3:

Here is the code for `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(postCellIdentifier) as? PostCell

        if cell == nil {
           cell = PostCell()
        }

        if let postCell = cell,
            let postArray = postArray,
            let post = postArray[indexPath.row] {
            postCell.post = post
            return postCell
        }

        // This section is hit during a refresh.
        let emptyCell = UITableViewCell()
        emptyCell.contentView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
        return emptyCell

    }
```

Edit 4:

I've found that if I "prime" the `UIImageView` by pre-setting a placeholder image in the nib, then load my image into that `UIImageView`, the image will display at the height of the placeholder. When I pull that cell offscreen then on again, the `UIImageView` will paint the image at the correct size using the constraints setup in the nib.

So it seems the constraints and size of the `UIImageView` have been set by the time the image loads, and pulling it off/on screen causes a redraw of some kind that resizes the image properly. If I could programmatically trigger that redraw it would help, but see above for what I've already tried.

Edit 6:

Here it is in action. Note that I've set a placeholder image in the nib. This seems to cause the image to show when initially loaded, but at the dimensions of the placeholder. Scrolling it offscreen briefly causes the resizing, when it then displays correctly.
[image]

Edit 7:

I use PostView nib elsewhere in my app with no problem. When it loads the image is sized correctly. The problem only seems to present itself with the nib is embedded within a `UITableViewCell`.

Edit 8:

I found the root cause of this issue, called in viewDidLoad of my `UIViewController`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Using automatic dimension causes the initial incorrect row height. For some reason, scrolling the cell out/into view will recalculate the row height correctly and the image is displayed at the right height. Removing this code will display the image, but the row heights don't benefit from the auto height calculation. What is the best method to auto-calculate row heights and still avoid this problem?

Comment: when are you calling dataTaskWithURL ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri It is called in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I fetch a custom `UITableViewCell` with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. I then set an object on that cell, which has a `didSet` that fetches the image.

Comment: `self.pictureView.image = image` or                                 `cell.pictureView.image = image` ?

Comment: post your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for more detail, plz.

Comment: @Proton I've added more detail to show why it is set on self, not cell. The contents of the cell is a nib, and that nib sets the image on self. See edits 2 and 3.

Comment: @bluedome I've added more detail and posted that function. Please see edits 2 and 3.

Comment: You said that the dataTaskWithURL is called in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, but it doesn't exist in Edit 3? Are you sure it's not being called in the cell?

Comment: When your Request returns, the Cell might already be DEQUEUED and not visible on the screen, make sure thats not the case.

Comment: use the other method to dequeue cells, your current code may create bad cells without any image views, can't see enough of your code to be sure. also, debug the view when the image is ready - what views are there?

Comment: You don't need to use this: `if cell == nil { cell = PostCell()}` because if you create the cell on StoryBoard (or IB) always be available. Also you can use `!` on the wrapping of the cell.

Comment: @max_ cellForRowAtIndexPath dequeues a PostCell which loads a PostView nib. cellForRowAtIndexPath then sets a Post object on PostCell, and PostCell sets that Post object on the PostView nib. This triggers the didSet on PostView.post, which starts the dataTaskWithURL process. Sorry if this was not clear. There is a lot going on in this code and I'm trying to show only the relevant parts for simplicity.

Comment: @ogres My test only loads a single cell, and I've verified that it is onscreen when the image load takes place.

Comment: @Wain Setting breakpoints in the code shows that the all my outlet views exist (not nil) at the time the image is downloaded. It set the image but seemingly does not resize the `UIImageView` to handle it. Please see Edit 4.

Comment: Did you try: `tableView.beginUpdates(); tableView.endUpdates;` in the async block?

Comment: @AlexanderLi That async block sits in the class for the PostView nib. There isn't a reference to the `UITableView` I can use there.

Comment: @Fook Did you try "reloadRowsAtIndexPath" for the cell, after loading data for the cell? Trigger this function will eagerly reload the cell view. I cannot tell you the exact problem in your code now, but will this  help you overcome the problem ?

Comment: You don't need a reference to the tableView to call "reloadRowsAtIndexPath", just create a callback (Swift Closures) for reloading the row, and assign it to the cell in "cellForRowAtIndexPath". You call this callback when the data is fully loaded in the cell code.

Comment: @HoaiDam The problem seems to be `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Please see Edit 8 in my question.

Comment: Add an answer that is really more of a reference to a solution to the init issue in edit 8, from a similar problem. It includes a really lovely solution I use myself now, from Martin R, in response to a related issue.

Comment: @AlexanderLi Your technique of calling `beginUpdates()` followed by `endUpdates()` is the only method that actually triggered the `UIImageView` resize programmatically, even though it doesn't seem this is the intended use of those functions. If you post this as an answer I will award the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this extension:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(link link:String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode) {
        guard
            let url = NSURL(string: link)
            else {return}
        contentMode = mode
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.MIMEType where mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data where error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                self.image = image
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

And then you can put this line wherever you want

```
cell.cellPhoto.downloadedFrom(link: "customImageUrl", contentMode: .ScaleAspectFit) //Try changing contentMode
```

Comment: The problem seems to be `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Please see Edit 8 in my question.

Comment: use heightForRow method in table view delegate. So you will calculate the row height. If dont have image at that moment use default height and then reload cell row when the image is fetched.

Comment: Nice extension mate! I only have one issue. If the image is large it doesnt download it and it shows a blank image

Comment: Thanks :). How large is your image?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [WWDC 2014 Session 226](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/226/) ? The video maybe shed some more light on your issue.

In the WWDC session they use `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;` **which you have done**✅ and then they say you then do not need any kind of dummy prototype cell from the table view controller.

The issue then is that when the storyboard loads the table view it sets the `rowHeight` property to the value from xib/interface builder. To make use of auto-sizing cells you need to set `estimatedRowHeight` and leave `rowHeight` to what should be the default - `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. (**which you have done**)✅

`self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

⚠️The new problem is that the first cells load before you have a bona fide row height. The trick is maybe to force a table reload when the view shows?

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated]
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

If this does not work then maybe you unintentionally set an *explicit* contentWidth/Height on something that is causing it not to be sized properly❓❓

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your tableview data after the download is complete. try calling `self.tableview.reloadData()` inside `dispatch_async` block

And also if you want to download image from a URL asynchronously I recommend using [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

Comment: I did try this but it did not help. The problem seems to be `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Please see Edit 8 in my question.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the course of edits (8 currently) and updates from your responders, it seems like you are running into an the same error in the init method that caused the [errors in init mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591364/custom-uitableviewcell-not-using-xib-most-likely-because-of-flaw-in-init-metho).

Credit should be given to Prcela being on the right track with registering the nib, but a more elegant solution is provided below:

> The easiest way (available since iOS 5.0) to create a custom table view cell in a nib file is to use registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: in the table view controller. The big advantage is that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: then automatically instantiates a cell from the nib file if necessary. You don't need the if (cell == nil) ... part anymore.

In the Table View Controller under `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CueTableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CueTableCell"];
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` add

```
CueTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CueTableCell"];
// setup cell
return cell;
```

> Cells loaded from a nib file are instantiated using initWithCoder, you
>   can override that in your subclass if necessary. For modifications to
>   the UI elements, you should override awakeFromNib (don't forget to
>   call "super").

I wish I could take credit for such an elegant solution, but that credit belongs to [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) from the same post.

Comment: The problem is that updating the image within the custom cell does not initially trigger an update of the layout. The `UIImageView` does not refresh until it is pulled off screen, then onscreen, at which point a redraw(?) occurs and the image is displayed. If I preset a placeholder image on the `UIImageView` my downloaded image is displayed with the placeholder image height, and is resized only after it goes offscreen, then onscreen. The solution to this problem will be how to trigger that resize programmatically after the download.