# UILabel overlapping in UITableView Cell using storyboards with auto layouts

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout

I am trying to add 2 labels in my table view cell.
when in portrait mode the both labels overlap each other and in landscape mode it works fine.

I have also used auto-layout . Where i have to make changes to achieve the target.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"ProductTableViewCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel * productName= (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];


    //productName.text=[[productDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]product_Name]; 
    // similar code for another label also 

    productName.lineBreakMode= NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    productName.numberOfLines=0;
    productName.text= @"asdfasdfsdzxcvzasdfaxv";
    [productName sizeToFit];

    return cell;
    }
```

Link for Issue for better description : http://f.talk.to/3afcd0c13764064184c01cc4

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you trying to use a custom UITableViewCell? Where is the 'productName' UILabel coming from?

Comment: yup i am trying to use custom UITableViewCell and in the storyboard on the product detail view controller i have a table view in which i have a cell and there i have used 2 labels. with tag 101 and 102 .

Comment: Where are you initializing and loading your custom cell? From the code above it seems that your tableCells are `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` cells.

Comment: i have used :
 if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

Comment: Yes, but that will only give you a 'default' or 'out-of-the-box' cell, not a custom one. Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files) for how to load custom UITableViewCells.

Comment: Are you registering your custom UITableViewCell NIB somewhere else in your code?

Comment: No i am not , Just put a label on the cell and given a tab to it and in the table view delegate check for the tag and populate the value . But i am able to get the value in my table view ..

Comment: have a look what i did :http://f.talk.to/3afcd0c13764090857ea64da

Comment: or  you can suggest any other solution .. !! will be a great help ..:)

Comment: How you're loading your custom cell is just perplexing to me. But it digresses from your question, so if I figure something out about your overlapping issue I'll post an answer.

Comment: do you need more code ?