# iOS objects return nil soon after creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nested, null

so I'm writing Obj-C for iOS, and something "strange" is happening..

I have an MVC, with a UITableView (private):

```
@interface MVC ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CellVC *cell1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CellVC *cell2;

@end
```

I load the table view up with a few custom cells.  My custom cell class is actually a UIViewController... so I instantiate a few, and set cell.contentView to the corresponding CellVC.view inside the **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** method.   My custom cell class:

```
@interface CellVC : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIKnob *knob1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIKnob *knob2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIKnob *knob3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIKnob *knob4;

@end
```

In case you're wondering, I've written a subclass of UIControl named UIKnob...

In CellVC's **viewDidAppear:** method, I've set a breakpoint to check the values of every knob. Each knob is non-nil, so I am happy... they have all been created.

My goal is to set MVC as the delegate of each knob. (4 knobs for each cell) 
If I set a breakpoint anywhere in MVC, the value of each knob is nil??...

```
cell1.knob1.delegate = self;
```

will not work because the knobs only exist inside CellVC.m ...

Any ideas??

Comment: Your custom cell is a UIViewController?  That is not going to work.  UITableView manages UITableViewCell objects and nothing else.  For starters put your custom views inside a UITableViewCell.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely start there... A friend wrote the CellVC class and it seemed to be working just fine in the app until now when I need to set the delegate. Thanks man

Comment: check this out.....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files

Comment: The first answer shows a UIViewController being loaded from a .XIB and thrown into a TableViewCell.. which is just a view