# Cannot load data in custom cells in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Please help me with UITableViewCells.

I have followed many tutorials and sites but didn't get my problem solved.

I have tried to make a simpleCustomCells app but data are not loaded in the table view.

1.I have a table view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil]];

    for(id obj in nib)
    {
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (CustomCell *)obj;
        }
    }    
}


cell.label.text = @"hello";

return cell;
}
```

Also tried

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

"within `if(cell==nill)`"

2.I have created CustomCell : UITableViewCell with only a UILabel outlet. Changed CustomCell.xib identifier's name.

When I run this app I get this kind of error:

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x71627f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class
 is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.
```

Please Help me with this issue, where am I going wrong.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/q/540345/1480518?

Comment: Yes I have tried that and getting the same error.

Comment: Why are you testing if it's a `UITableViewCell` when it needs to be a `CustomCell`?

Comment: Did you set the cell's class to your custom class? Do you actually have CustomCell.m/h files?

Comment: Yes I do have CustomCell.h/m files. I have used CustomCell instead ofUITableViewCell. Do you have solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got where you are getting stuck.

Step 1 : **Disconnect** the outlet `UILabel` from the **xib** file.

Step 2 : Go to your xib file and you will see your objects list on the left hand side of the xib file.

Step 3 : Take your mouse pointer just below where objects is written. You will find `Custom Cell` written.

Step 4 : Press **ctrl** and drag it to the label and now **Connect** the Outlet to label.

Step 5 : **Clean** your program and **Run** it again.

All the best. If you still have doubts, I will elaborate. :)

Comment: Yes I got it now. I was connecting the label by clicking right of the mouse. I did it as u said by click right of the CustomCell. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add like this, I hope it works

```
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  customcellCell *cell = (customcellCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   <- set your customclass in this line.

  if (cell == nil)
   {
      NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customviewcell" owner:self options:nil];
      cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }

    cell.label.text = @"hello";

   return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following way :

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       ContactListCell *contactCell;

        NSString *contactCellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ContactCell%d%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];
        contactCell = (ContactListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:contactCellID];

        if(!contactCell) {
            contactCell = [[ContactListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:contactCellID];
            contactCellID = nil;
        }

        strName = @"First name";

      contactCell.lblFirstName.text = [strName capitalizedString];

      return contactCell;
    }
```

**For Custom cell  .h file**

```
@interface ContactListCell : UITableViewCell {

    UILabel *lblFirstName;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *lblFirstName;
@end
```

**For Custom cell  .m file**

```
@implementation ContactListCell

@synthesize lblFirstName;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
 self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

    lblFirstName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kxiPadFirstNameCellLandscape, kyiPadFirstNameCellLandscape, kiPadFirstNameCellWidthLandscape, kiPadFirstNameCellHeightLandscape)];
                lblFirstName.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
                lblFirstName.numberOfLines = 0;
                lblFirstName.textColor = kCustomCellFontColor;
                [self.contentView addSubview:lblFirstName];

    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not give you're cell an identifier and instantiate it with dequewithreusableidentifier?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";


CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[AanbodTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.Label.text =@"Hello"


return cell;
}
```

i would also refer to this very good tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Yes I have used cell identifier as well. Still I didn't get my problem solved.

Comment: Yes I think label is correctly defined: @property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

Comment: The outlet connection was incorrect. I had made connection by clicking right on the label . Now I did it by clicking right on the CustomCell . Surprisingly it worked. Thanks