# setting the size of the image added to cell in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am adding images to my cell view from a plist. Also I have the same issue with images that I save to the plist using a url as well. They are different sizes. I'd like to resize them to certain size so they would all appear the same. I have tried to use:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

It did not work. I have tried a bunch of other things and did not succeed. I have looked up a bunch of stuff and can't find anything helpful. Here is my cell for row method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"city"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"state"];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityImage"]];
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"city"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"state"];
        // Construct the expected URL for the image.
        NSURL *imageFileURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask][0];
        imageFileURL = [imageFileURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityImage"] isDirectory:NO];
        // Attempt to load the image at the above URL.
        cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[imageFileURL path]];
        if (!cell.imageView.image)
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityImage"]];
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

For the life of me I can't figure this out. I know it might be a easy fix but i can't think of anything else.

**Edit:**

As suggested, I created a custom cell, declared layoutSubviews in there and then subclassed the cell as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MyCostumCell *cell = (MyCostumCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyCostumCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"city"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"state"];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityImage"]];
        //cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153.0/255.0f green:0.0/255.0f blue:0.0/255.0f alpha:1];
    } else {

        cell.textLabel.text = [[content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"city"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"state"];
        // Construct the expected URL for the image.
        NSURL *imageFileURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask][0];
        imageFileURL = [imageFileURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityImage"] isDirectory:NO];
        // Attempt to load the image at the above URL.
        cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[imageFileURL path]];
        if (!cell.imageView.image)
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityImage"]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Again, it did not work. Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: you should definitely do some reading of the documentary. your  wording is totally confused. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you dont subclass the cell. u use a subclassed cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you would subclass UITableViewCell. but you dont have to create a whole new view hierachy as proposed by Dante, but overwrite `-layoutSubviews`

```
@interface VideoItemCell : UITableViewCell
@end


@implementation VideoItemCell
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x, self.imageView.frame.origin.y, 100, 100);
}

@end
```

In the tableview controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    VideoItemCell *cell = (VideoItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[VideoItemCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    }

    //…
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i tried to add the method and i get the error no visible @interface for uitableview declares the selector layoutsubview.

Comment: you need to subclass the cell, not the table view

Comment: man, you dont like reading manuals, right? subclassing cells is very much standard. but as you ask super politely: here you go.

Comment: thanks for being awesome and try to help. but somehow it did not work for me. i posted the edit part of my question with a screen shot. thanks again for your time.

Comment: it would be helpful if you'd show us your layoutSubviews (please dont tll me, that you didnt adapt it to your needs)

Comment: The layout sub view is exactly what you posted. I just created a class for it and ace them there the imposrt the classic tableview and subclasses it as you mentioned.

Comment: yeah, and how am I supposed to know what you need inside? I am not a mind reader. You will ave to adapted it.

Comment: iE: I took this code from a app where the row height is at leas 200px.  So 100x100px images will fit easily. you have the standart heitht of 44px.

Comment: or is it 70px? so try `self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x, self.imageView.frame.origin.y, 70, 52);
`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'll try to fix the mistakes I possibly made tonight when I get home and let you know. Once again thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Thanks for your input and guidance. Sub classing was the way to go. Although for that app that I needed help with, I went with dumb way of resizing my images but i have adapted the sub classing the cell in the updates and the other projects I'm working on. Thanks again man.

Answer (score 1):

Default TableViewCell resizes imageview based on image size. To solve this you can use a custom cell having a custom Image View ..

More info on how to create custom cell

[How do you load custom UITableViewCells from Xib files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files)

Comment: thanks for the link, but it is way too old and does not work. also i have tried the custom cell creating the image through a image view and assigned tags to it. that did not work either. anything else you can suggest?

Comment: the answer still works.. you might try to google a proper tutorial step by step which can help you do it properly