# TableView cell image size

Tags: uitableview

I use Apple's example LazyTableImages to lazy loading image to my table view cell. The default cell height is 60 and icon size is 48 ( in IconDownloader.m "kAppIconSize 48").
But if i change the cell height to 100 and icon size to 90 and it's not working.

When i reload tableView, is show up image with 90 but after 0,5 second return to 48.

I want to show up the covers of films and books with height = 90 and width = 55.

How and where can i edit the code?

In tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath or IconDownloader.m?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a duplicate question of [setting the size of the image added to cell in tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253239/setting-the-size-of-the-image-added-to-cell-in-tableview)

Basically overwrite -layoutSubviews and set the image size to whatever you want.