# UITableViewCell - Change Visited/active background color

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to change the visited / Active style for a UITableView Cell?

I have styled the inactive state using the storyboard gui interface - but there doesnt seem to be options for the other possible states..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no default way to handle the different styles for tableView cells, but you should have no issue implementing that behaviour on your own by subclassing the UITableViewCell and adding the required behaviour by changing the backgroundView depending on an arbitrary state.

There's a good amount of information here:
[How do you load custom UITableViewCells from Xib files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files)

And a tutorial link from the same question:
http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/

Comment: cool - cheers Adis - had a quick play and think I can figure it out with the above..