# visited custom UITableViewCell weird selection behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm getting some weird behavior in my `UITableViewController`.

I've subclassed UITableViewCell and created by own "visited" property within it.

```
- (void)setVisited:(BOOL)visited animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self setVisited:visited];
    ...
}
```

I set this property when I create the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (the only place I create it) like below:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ArticleListViewCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier art:art index:indexPath.row];
    [cell setVisited:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Later, in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, I set this property to `YES`:

```
ArticleListViewCell *cell = (ArticleListViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setVisited:YES animated:NO];
```

However, when I select a cell and then return to this `UITableView`, which currently has 10 cells, I find that not only has the cell I selected become "visited", but also another cell has as well. It's hard to explain, but if I select the 1st cell, the 7th also becomes visited, if I select the 2nd, the 8th also becomes visited, and so on. Does anyone know why this is, and how I should go about fixing it?

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522590/uitableviewcell-change-visited-active-background-color), but it doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: Cells are reused, so that's why you get that result. You need to keep track of the index paths of any visited cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by cell reuse. You need to set `visited` every time, not just when you create the cell.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ArticleListViewCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier art:art index:indexPath.row];
}

BOOL visited = ... // value for this indexPath
[cell setVisited:visited animated:NO];
```

And in your `didSelectRow` method you need to update some sort of data structure keeping track of which row has been visited. You use this data to set the value properly in the `cellForRow` method.

Do not use the cell to keep track of state. The cell is a view. Your data source needs to track the state.

Comment: Thanks -- I should be keeping the state in a data source; I was mostly just confused as to why the views were changing in that particular way.