# tableView.register(nib) loses auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xib

in my `viewDidLoad` I register my nib:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
```

which I fetch in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell") as? MyCell else {
    return UITableViewCell()
}
// I do get here, but no constraints exist
```

In my `MyCell.xib` which is a `UITableViewCell`, I layout my cell content with auto layout; but when running the app, all the cells subviews stick in the upper left, no constraints exist.

How can I achieve that the auto layout of `MyCell.xib` 'survives'?

Comment: What are all your constraints?

Comment: constraints regarding the centerY of the contentView, leading constraints.

Comment: What is the value of `cell.translateAutoResizingMaskIntoconstraints` ??

Comment: try this solution you need to get cell as same like as : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1939305/3901620

Comment: Would you show your cell's layout?

Comment: @NeverHopeless it's `true`, same for `cell.contentView` - but it's not enough to set it to `false` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`...

Comment: @swalkner, did you get any warning in debugger related to Unsatisfiable Constraints ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless no; and when I log the constraints of `cell` or `cell.contentView` they are empty: `[]`

Comment: In which event do you log them ? Perhaps adding more code related to setting up tableview and cell could be helpful for us to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: XCode version ?

Comment: `Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)`

Comment: In XCode 8.2 it seems to work fine, so i think problem is specifically related to v8.3. Can you please give this a try: https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8/issues/10 the `extension reloadDataWithAutoSizingCellWorkAround`

Comment: didn't help, unfortunately. Called that method in both, `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`

Comment: having the  same problem