# Can I use a tablecell which is containing in another tableview(from storyboard)?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Here is the cell I want to reuse.

[image]

And there is a related cell class.

```
class FlightTransitTBCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var abovebullet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomBullet: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var upBullet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var downBullet: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var lblAboveTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblButtomTime: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lblUpTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblDownTime: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lblAboveAirPort: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblButtomAirPort: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lblDownAirPort: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblUpAirPort: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var viaDown: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var viaUp: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    downBullet.text = "\u{2022}"
    upBullet.text = "\u{2022}"
    abovebullet.text = "\u{2022}"
    bottomBullet.text = "\u{2022}"

    downBullet.font = UIFont(name: getAppFont(), size: 20)
    upBullet.font = UIFont(name: getAppFont(), size: 20)
    abovebullet.font = UIFont(name: getAppFont(), size: 40)
    bottomBullet.font = UIFont(name: getAppFont(), size: 40)

}
}
```

Following is my xib, which contain a tableview that I'm trying to display above cell.

[image]

And I register the cell from the xib class like this.

```
tableView.register(FlightTransitTBCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TransitCell")
```

then dequeue from tableview like this..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let transitCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TransitCell") as? FlightTransitTBCell{
        transitCell.awakeFromNib()
        transitCell.selectionStyle = .none
        transitCell.setTransitView(indexPath.row, firstRoute, lastRoute)
        transitCell.setBullet(outward_[indexPath.row])
        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            transitCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
        return transitCell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

I got the cell and it means my registration is working. But all my outlets are being nil and giving me error. I don't know what I'm doing is proper way of not. I'm not sure. This is my first time of doing like that and stuck here.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated but never call `awakeFromNib` yourself. The method is exclusively called by the framework. It you need to share code put it into a custom method.

Comment: I removed that code but outcome is the same.

Comment: Your cell should be in a separate xib file if you want to reuse it across the project. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1939305/8314394)

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote *unrelated*.